# Revenue by job and total via access database

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I've got an excel imported database that contains the following: Job number, Employee ID, Employee Name, Revenue per job. I'm trying to create a query (which I'll later connect to a report) that shows total revenue for each employee. The query would be used to create a form that'll let us pick out an Employee ID from a combo box and see both totals and revenue per job.

Any ideas on how this can be accomplished?

I know it's easier done in excel via pivot tables but there's other things we need to do to the data that mean we need to do the same thing in access for now.

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Straightforward aggregate query. What is the problem?

Comment: Does `employee Id` and `employee name` will be same always?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the following...

```
SELECT [Employee ID],
       [Employee Name],
       SUM( [Revenue per job] ) AS TotalRevenue
FROM tblTable
GROUP BY [Employee ID];
```

The above query takes the table specified (in the absence of a tablename in your Question I have used `tblTable`).  It groups the records by `[Employee ID]` then calculates the total revenue for each group (i.e. for each employee), returning the total with the other fields specified.

If you have any questions or comments, then please feel free to post a Comment accordingly.

Comment: That was it. That's what I was looking for. Thank you so much!

Comment: New at SQL and Access :/